# Changing TreeGrid Styling in ExtJs 4

Tags: extjs4, treegrid

I am trying to change the styling with alternate rows having different color for the sample treegrid : http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/tree/treegrid.html . How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `getRowClass` configuration?

```
viewConfig: {
    getRowClass: function(record) {
        if(!record) return '';
        if(record.data.id == user.id) return 'bg-yellow';
    }
},
```

Comment: I tried the getRowClass. For the first time when tree gets loaded, the alternate row styling is working good. But, when i do expand or collapse of any node, this styling doesn't work. Any way Thanks for your reply.